# use openssl to decrypt ciphertext created with python cryptography

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I encrypted a message using an rsa public key with [python cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/), and got the following bytes as the ciphertext.

```
b'.\xb6I#5\xdb\x99V\xa7Rd\x9d\xc6?\xe6\xfb\x15\xb4LQb\xf4\t\xe8,\x96\xce\xf9<\x95\xefN(D$zJx\\w0\'\tet\x0c\x1e\xd0\x98\x9cS\xadMnW\\-\x81\x1c\\\xe1+\xf6\xf0\xc5=\x11F\xd9r3J\xa2\xb9Th\x06N\xdc\xba\x0f\x84 w\xf9"\xbf\xc8*-\xc3\x7f\xc4\x86>\x11,*\x1c(\xc2\xd8\xc2l\x9b\xc5\xa1\xda\xd4FGz\xee\x00\x9a\xd3al.p\r\nIg\xba)\xa4\rt\xe7\x8c\x04o}T\x9aY O\xe8M\x83\x82H\xc8K\xd2\x10\r\xb5\xac\x97\x03<\xfac\x87p\xe7q\x85M\xe3x\xefB\xe1\xb5\xf3\xa7\xbf\xa1g<w\xd2\x97>\xf8\x8e+^A\xc1\x88j(\x8d\xf5\xba\xed\xa8\x87[\x14\x19\x9bq\xd2\xc0\x9e\'\x9f\xbbu\xda\xb3bPu\x95{+R\xa6\x1cw(\'a\xa0\x88;\xca{\xf2\xe9Sr;\x81r\x84`\x87\x1a\x979\xfc\x8b\xbf%\xb5w\\D\xf8\xc2]g\x82#?\x94C\x17msIX~l\xcc\xb4KL\x02\xae)\xa7dzM7\xad3\xc3\x9b\xe8\x81m\xa7s\xed\xaa\xf4\x82\x16\x9e\xf4\xf7\xee\xd4\xc0 y\x9e\xe3C@P\x8e\x83\xe1\x07\xdf9\x9cI\x84\xfd\ts.\xd1qy\xa1\x17\xd0\xbd\x05\xe9]\xfaP\xfbM\xee\xf1\x04\xc3\n\xa9\xdf\x80Y\x11\xac4eBV\xf0\xd6\xa1/[\xd0!\xfe\xda\x1b\x1d(\x87h\x91\xd4"\xdfO\x16\xd6b\xaa\x048\xc9\xff\x1aVGB\xbe\x00\xd5\x8f\xcb\xad\x13\x86\xb8\xb6]\xaa\xf5\xf5\x89[Q\x16\x01\x14\xb0f\xb2\xd3\xb0\xe40\x1c\x07R\xa4\x91\xac\xcc\x92\x83-\x13\x11\xdf\x06\xee\x86wf\xf5\xa3\xe9>\xfcFx\x9dA\x04\xbc\xfa g\xf4@x\xa5\x19M;\xe0\xea\r\x8e\x11_\x0e\xbe\xc1\x91\x8a\x88\xd6\xd6z\xbbI\xc6\x83W\x06\xd7\xd6\x94\xf1\x0cL\x10{t5\x10\xc2\xeb\xbb\xd3u\xce\r\xde\xa9\x9b\x9bT\x05\x89\xbb\xb6\xda\x18*\xf5\x0b\x95pS\x06iz\x8b{\xce#\xa6\xe3\xf1u\xa4O(L\xc9'
```

I will like to decrypt it with the private key using openssl but the format is not accepted in openssl.

can someone please tell me how to use python  to convert the ciphertext to an format openssl can read?

i see the same encrypted message in openssl is like this:

```
7~╛♦b»{♂φ"☼♠( ╧é÷G,■ò‼▲╞Dë}º∙╢╡²∟╔►;àªσùJ─₧O_¥√ú♣L_ü«3╖'ä(^£▒╨É╝p█E..m&╟⌐{O
╛⌡x÷°xêVt∟▄k-↔ô┤A#├│síâ‼≈ⁿ;=:╩÷í≡
I▒√═.╧Iu₧♀9*él]D╤│äTÖ╩ó;"┐╩├τµ▀ΦOhÇÉæ─j♀└∞:Öm┌↓iδVOV↕à░)╜lñ⌠α☻-╝s¥aD▲ⁿ☺±╙²2
µ▬/B?│}'4G║áû5╟╖É╗x▄╨→╧├jj┐ïDè%ÆφàT1♦åΘ╘cª↓°3]a∙ö┐·■BÄê|q5Od╢A~Y8ó↓╙ÄUπ ╪▲σ
:═5ç~≤♥à╘↨[½y→g&ù╡å±¡√1L?Np╞W⌐▼rXÄΩ!╡WrxGeª╡ ça∞φ╠S↕}M⌂ñπé=┤░H╛½▲-â·wh₧J=⌠[
╥_Y@φê;oU;¢☺xäÜª┐pR↓àqⁿ╣L^╫¿█çΩâ↕ße¼└←dUπß¶)aÑó╧εI      tφfê╟/αá╬<rK_╔m♠⌐╩Z
,!▐☻p♠-Ää'¼µ╛╨B2]í!A┌}╤╩}└ÄG▼xWx8A|τEH‼
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either base 64 encode it in python and then decode it in openssl, or use a binary method of communication between the two applications (a file or a pipe).

Comment: am I to encode to encrypted data?